# PyKCS11 unhashable list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror, pkcs#11

A python script of mine is designed to get detailed information of slots/tokens in a particular .so library. The output looks like this:

```
Library manufacturerID: Safenet, Inc.                   
Available Slots: 4
Slot no: 0
slotDescription: ProtectServer K5E:00045
manufacturerID: SafeNet Inc.
TokenInfo
label: CKM
manufacturerID: SafeNet Inc.
model: K5E:PL25
Opened session 0x00000002

Found 38 objects: [5021, 5022, 5014, 5016, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16, 18, 23, 24, 26, 27, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 38, 39, 5313, 5314, 4982, 5325, 5326, 5328, 5329, 5331, 5332, 5335, 5018, 4962, 5020, 4963]
```

I am able to open the session and get the information. Where I run into dubious problems is retrieving the attributes of said keys in the library.

I created my own template for desired attributes needed for my specifications, the following:

```
    all_attributes = PyKCS11.CKA.keys()
    # only use the integer values and not the strings like 'CKM_RSA_PKCS'
    all_attributes = [e for e in all_attributes if isinstance(e, int)]
    attributes = [
            ["CKA_ENCRYPT", PyKCS11.CKA_ENCRYPT],
            ["CKA_CLASS", PyKCS11.CKA_CLASS],
            ["CKA_DECRYPT", PyKCS11.CKA_DECRYPT],
            ["CKA_SIGN", PyKCS11.CKA_SIGN],
            ["CKA_VERIFY", PyKCS11.CKA_VERIFY],
            ["CKA_ID", PyKCS11.CKA_ID],
            ["CKA_MODULUS", PyKCS11.CKA_MODULUS],
            ["CKA_MODULUS", PyKCS11.CKA_MODULUS],
            ["CKA_MODULUS_BITS", PyKCS11.CKA_MODULUS_BITS],
            ["CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT", PyKCS11.CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT],
            ["CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT", PyKCS11.CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT],
            ]
```

I'm getting an unhashable type: 'list' TypeError when trying to dump the attributes on the following block:

```
print "Dumping attributes:"
        for q, a in zip(all_attributes, attributes):
            if a == None:
                # undefined (CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID) attribute
                continue
            if q == PyKCS11.CKA_CLASS:
                print format_long % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], PyKCS11.CKO[a], a)
            elif q == PyKCS11.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE:
                print format_long % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], PyKCS11.CKC[a], a)
            elif q == PyKCS11.CKA_KEY_TYPE:
                print format_long % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], PyKCS11.CKK[a], a)
            elif session.isBin(q):
                print format_binary % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], len(a))
                if a:
                    print dump(''.join(map(chr, a)), 16),
            elif q == PyKCS11.CKA_SERIAL_NUMBER:
                print format_binary % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], len(a))
                if a:
                    print hexdump(a, 16),
            else:
                print format_normal % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], a)
```

This line specifically is generating the error:

```
if q == PyKCS11.CKA_CLASS:
            print format_long % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], PyKCS11.CKO[a], a)
```

I understand that you can't use a list as the key in a dict, since dict keys need to be immutable. How would I use a tuple in this situation?

Comment: What do you mean *"implement a tuple"*? Do you mean *use* one? Just use it! `attributes = [("CKA_ENCRYPT", PyKCS11.CKA_ENCRYPT), ...]`.

Comment: Doesn't the generated line expand to `print format_long % (PyKCS11.CKA[PyKCS11.CKA_CLASS], PyKCS11.CKO[["CKA_ENCRYPT", PyKCS11.CKA_ENCRYPT]], ["CKA_ENCRYPT", PyKCS11.CKA_ENCRYPT])`? Just use one, as suggested by @jonrsharpe.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was confusing myself. However, new error arises `KeyError: ('CKA_ENCRYPT', 260)` on the same line `print format_long % (PyKCS11.CKA[q], PyKCS11.CKO[a], a)`

Comment: Ok, so that key is missing. Go find out why.

Comment: No, the `CKA_ENCRYPT` attribute isn't applicable for the given object in the slot. @jonrsharpe

Comment: The key isn't missing.. however I only need access to one of the objects via defining the `label name` of the specific object I need. I am unsure of how to do this @jonrsharpe

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer was put together in the context of your other questions)

To read attributes of a PKCS#11 object `o` you can use the following code:

```
# List which attributes you want to read
attributeIds = [
    CKA_ENCRYPT,
    CKA_CLASS,
    CKA_DECRYPT,
    CKA_SIGN,
    CKA_VERIFY,
    CKA_ID,
    CKA_MODULUS,
    CKA_MODULUS_BITS,
    CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT,
    CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT
]

# Read them
attributeValues = session.getAttributeValue(o, attributeIds)

# Print them (variant 1 -- more readable)
for i in range(0,len(attributeIds)):
    attributeName = CKA[attributeIds[i]]
    print("Attribute %s: %s" % (attributeName, attributeValues[i]))

# Print them (variant 2 -- more consise)
for curAttrId, currAttrVale in zip(attributeIds,attributeValues):
    attributeName = CKA[curAttrId]
    print("Attribute %s: %s" % (attributeName, currAttrVale))
```

Some additional (random) notes:

- the [Session.getAttributeValue() method](http://pkcs11wrap.sourceforge.net/api/PyKCS11.Session-class.html#getAttributeValue) method requires a list of attribute ids. You are constructing a list of "lists containing *Attribute name (string)* and *Attribute id (int)*" -- without any conversion -- this can't work
- the `CKA_PRIVATE_EXPONENT` attribute is sensitive for RSA private keys. You probably won't be able to read it unless the `CKA_SENSITIVE` attribute is set to `False` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14933297/5128464))
- be sure to read only valid attributes for specific object (based on type, mechanism, sensitivity...)
- the snippet above does not use the `PyKCS11.` prefix to reference PyKCS11 object members as it assumes they are imported with `from PyKCS11 import *` directive (I am not enough into python to tell you which way is the good one)
- the attribute id <-> attribute name mapping is based on fact, that the `PKCS11.CKA` dictionary contains both string keys with int values and int keys with string keys (you can dump this dictionary yourself or check the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/PyKCS11/pykcs11/src/856b967cefb0e946d4b03614f71ddcaa9cbd8153/PyKCS11/__init__.py?at=1.3.2&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-77))
- it might be much easier to dump the attributes with `print(o)`
- I would recommend reading relevant parts of the [PKCS#11 standard](https://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-11-cryptographic-token-interface-standard.htm)
- (you might get your answer faster if you referenced [the origins of your thoughts](https://bitbucket.org/PyKCS11/pykcs11/src/856b967cefb0e946d4b03614f71ddcaa9cbd8153/samples/dumpit.py?at=1.3.2&fileviewer=file-view-default#dumpit.py-224))

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Very interesting additional notes. ```try:
                attributeValues = session.getAttributeValue(o, attributeIds)
            except PyKCS11.PyKCS11Error as e:
                print("error", e)``` is giving me an `CKA_ATTRIBUTE_TPYE_INVALID` when i remove the exception is **not** ignored. I'll have to figure out what is causing this specifically. @vlp

Comment: So I double checked the actual attributes and their values on our remote machine. Removed the ones on the list that weren't present and added a few more. I found something interesting. It did output attributes of the `5328` object. So for example. ```============ Object: 5328 =============
Attribute CKA_KEY_TYPE: 0
Attribute CKA_CLASS: 3
Attribute CKA_DECRYPT: True
Attribute CKA_SIGN: True
Attribute CKA_ID: (32, 22, 3, 22, 0, 4)```    The boolean values are obviously true, however the `ID` `KEY_TYPE`, etc. are outputting weird numeric values, what could be causing this ? @vlp

Comment: Also, the different examples referring to more readable/concise had no noticeable differences when printed.

Comment: And never mind it's just two different representations of a byte array. using a data type converter all the values match appropriately

Comment: @DJ2 Exactly -- you need to read the appropriate attributes for given object class (as determined by `CKA_CLASS` and `CKA_KEY_TYPE` /for key objects/).

Comment: @DJ2 The two ways of printing attributes with values are meant to do the same -- I only wanted to show you the `for i in range(...):` construct which I find more readable for c/java programmers. Good luck reading [the PKCS#11 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/pkcs11-base-v2.40.pdf)!