# how to use ePass3003 token in python for digital signature?

Tags: python, rsa, digital-signature, signature, pkcs#11

I want to use Python to connect to the ePass3003 token to sign a string or data from JSON and sign it (everything I want to sign, I said JSON as an example)
I know that it is not possible to extract the private key in this token
However, I have the following piece of code, but it gives me an error

```
from PyKCS11 import *


# Initialize the PKCS#11 library
lib = 'E:/lib_x64/ShuttleCsp11_3003.dll'  



pkcs11 = PyKCS11Lib()
pkcs11.load(lib)

# Open a session
slot = pkcs11.getSlotList()[0]  
session = pkcs11.openSession(slot)

try:
    # Login with PIN 
    session.login('1234')


    private_key = session.findObjects([(CKA.CLASS, CKO.PRIVATE_KEY), (CKA.LABEL, 'PrivateKeyLabel')])[0]

    # Data to be signed
    data_to_sign = b'Your data to be signed'

    # Sign the data
    signature = session.sign(private_key, data_to_sign, Mechanism(CKM.RSA_PKCS))

    print("signature==> ",signature)

    # 'signature' now contains the RSA-256 signature of the data
except PyKCS11Error as e:
    print(f"PyKCS11 error: {e}")
finally:
    session.logout()
    session.closeSession()
```

ERROR:
`private_key = session.findObjects([(CKA.CLASS, CKO.PRIVATE_KEY), (CKA.LABEL, 'PrivateKeyLabel')])[0]`

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'CLASS'`

There is one more thing that I don't know what to put instead of PrivateKeyLabel, I don't know where to find this label
I can't find anything called private key label in the picture below
[ePass3003 app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CX4m.png)

I would be very grateful if someone could help me

Answer (score 1):

Did you get this from ChatGPT?

Change

```
private_key = session.findObjects([(CKA.CLASS, CKO.PRIVATE_KEY), (CKA.LABEL, 'PrivateKeyLabel')])[0]
```

for

```
private_key = session.findObjects([(CKA_CLASS, CKO_PRIVATE_KEY), (CKA_LABEL, 'PrivateKeyLabel')])[0]
```

There are not `CKA` or `CKO` objects with attributes, they're constants defined in the [pkcs11.h](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/PyKCS11/blob/cfcc30654d21dc1b695751bc06269290e548ce89/src/opensc/pkcs11.h#L374)

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920023/hsm-using-label-of-key-object-in-pkcs11)

Comment: Yes, I got this from ChatGPT
The point is that I want to create a JWT token using this code, but when I give the header and payload values to sign with these codes, I get the `CKR_DATA_LEN_RANGE error (0x00000021)`

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem